# Find the value of previous cell in csv

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find the cell value of a previous cell in the same column in the below csv. I will get the date and get the respective name it and find the previous cell value in the column.

```
startDate  endDate     Name
20-03-2019 30-03-2019  marchLogs
01-03-2019 15-03-2019  aprilLogs
```

---

```
$dt = Get-Date
Import-CSV filepath.csv
foreach($item in $csv)
{
$Start = $($item.StartDate)
$End = $($item.EndDate)
if($dt -gt $Start -and $dt -lt $End )
{
$finalName = $($item.Name)
# $previousName 
}
}
```

In the above code I will have the `$final` name value as `aprilLogs` , Now I need the previous name `marchLogs` in a new value `$previousName`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

- Access the csv data by index, if condition met use previous index
- using your forach and storing previous entry, if condition met ...

Or:

```
$finalName = (Import-CSV filepath.csv | 
 Where {[datetime]::parseexact($_.EndDate,"dd-MM-yyyy",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) -lt (Get-Date)} | 
  Sort {[datetime]::parseexact($_.EndDate,"dd-MM-yyyy",[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)} | Select -Last 1).Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dt = Get-Date
$csv = Import-Csv "filepath.csv"
foreach($item in $csv)
{
    $Start = $($item.StartDate)
    $End = $($item.EndDate)
    if($dt -gt $Start -and $dt -lt $End )
    {
        $index = $csv.Indexof($item)
        $previous = $csv[$index-1]
    }
}
$previous.Name
```